# incorrect textfield input obj c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, function

i have a problem with the management between app and sdk for a function. my app is divided into two parts: sdk and app.
this is my class for "sdk":

```
    - (void)statusCheckPin: (User *)pinUser
                  card: (Card *)pinCard
        viewController: (UIViewController *) viewController
              delegate: (id<LoyaltyCardsSDKCompleteDelegate>)delegate{

    self.delegate = delegate;

    SDKHandler* sdkHandler = [[SDKHandler alloc] initWithUserId:pinUser.userId fiscalCode:nil sessionToken:pinUser.sessionToken];

    [sdkHandler doStatusCheckPin:pinUser.userId card:pinCard.pan viewController:viewController
                         success:^(StatusCheckPinResponse* changePin) {

        Result<StatusCheckPinResponse *> *response = [[Result<StatusCheckPinResponse*> alloc] initWithStatusCode:MOBILE_GENERIC_ERROR_MSG andResponse:changePin];

        [self callDelegateForCommand:CMD_CHANGE_PIN WithResponse:response];

    } failure:^(Result *failureResult) {

        [self callDelegateForCommand:CMD_CHANGE_PIN WithResponse:failureResult];
    }];

    PRLog(@"SDK> Received cmd: STATUS CHECK PIN");

}



- (void) doStatusCheckPin: (NSString *) pinUser card: (NSString *) pinCard viewController: (UIViewController *) viewController success:(successSDKType)success failure:(failureSDKType)failure{

    self.mcCardEnrollmentSuccessCallback = success;
    self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback = failure;

    self.user = [[User alloc ]init];
    self.card = [[Card alloc ]init];

//    self.testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    self.testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[TestViewController class]]];


    if([self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"0"] ||
       [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"1"] ||
       [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"2"] ||
       [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"3"] ||
       [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"4"] ||
       [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"5"]){
        StatusCheckPinResponse *statusCheckPin = [[StatusCheckPinResponse alloc] init];
        [statusCheckPin setErrorCase:@"NOT_ENROLLED"];

        Result *errore = [[Result alloc] initWithStatusCode:@"2" andResponse:statusCheckPin];
        self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback(errore);

    } else if ([self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"6"] ||
               [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"7"] ||
               [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"8"] ||
               [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"9"]){
        StatusCheckPinResponse *statusCheckPin = [[StatusCheckPinResponse alloc] init];
        [statusCheckPin setErrorCase:@"ENROLLED"];

        Result *errore = [[Result alloc] initWithStatusCode:@"1" andResponse:statusCheckPin];
        self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback(errore);

    }
}
```

and this is my "app":

```
    case CHECK_PIN:{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.user = [[User alloc ]init];
        self.card = [[Card alloc ]init];

        self.user.userId = self.userIdPersonalTextField.text;
        self.user.sessionToken = self.sessionTokenPersonalTextField.text;
        self.user.fiscalCode = self.fiscalCodePersonalTextField.text;
        self.user.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberPersonalTextField.text;
        self.user.callerApp = self.callerAppPersonalTextField.text;
        self.card.pan = self.panPersonalTextField.text;
        self.card.driverCode = self.driverCodePersonalTextField.text;

        [self.loyaltySDK statusCheckPin:self.user card:self.card viewController:self delegate:self];
    });
}
```

that based on the number entered in the "pan" textfield, let me display 2 or 3 different answers.
the function I have to write better is this:

```
    if([self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"0"] ||
   [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"1"] ||
   [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"2"] ||
   [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"3"] ||
   [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"4"] ||
   [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"5"]){
    StatusCheckPinResponse *statusCheckPin = [[StatusCheckPinResponse alloc] init];
    [statusCheckPin setErrorCase:@"NOT_ENROLLED"];

    Result *errore = [[Result alloc] initWithStatusCode:@"2" andResponse:statusCheckPin];
    self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback(errore);

} else if ([self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"6"] ||
           [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"7"] ||
           [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"8"] ||
           [self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField isEqual: @"9"]){
    StatusCheckPinResponse *statusCheckPin = [[StatusCheckPinResponse alloc] init];
    [statusCheckPin setErrorCase:@"ENROLLED"];

    Result *errore = [[Result alloc] initWithStatusCode:@"1" andResponse:statusCheckPin];
    self.mcCardEnrollmentFailureCallback(errore);

}
```

that to tell the truth it doesn't work at all, because it always gets nil the textfield despite inserting the user in number ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are comparing a UITextField* with a NSString* , which would definitely not be doing what you intend.

```
    NSString* text = self.testViewController.panPersonalTextField.text;

    if( [text isEqualToString: @"0"] ||
        [text isEqualToString: @"1"] ||
        [text isEqualToString: @"2"] ||
        [text isEqualToString: @"3"] ||
        [text isEqualToString: @"4"] ||
        [text isEqualToString: @"5"] )
    {
        // do things
    }

    else if ( [text isEqualToString: @"6"] ||
              [text isEqualToString: @"7"] ||
              [text isEqualToString: @"8"] ||
              [text isEqualToString: @"9"] )
    {
        // do other things
    }
```

Might be enough to start you off, but it's hard to say without knowing more about the textfield. If your user's input is not limited to a single digit, you might want to add checking for that. Also, if there is a chance that this could be called when the textfield has no content, I usually like to compare strings this way, if there are constants involved:

```
if ( [@"constant string" isEqualToString:nullableVar] )
{
    // do things
}
```

There also isn't enough information in your question to see why these need to remain as NSStrings at all, otherwise you might consider adding all these codes to an enum, which would make your comparisons even easier.